# bluebird with ip-to-asn, unable to promisify

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

I want to get AS Name and AS Number for a list of IPS. Thers is a node package ip-to-asn  to do that. I tried to use bluebird to promisisify [ip-to-asn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip-to-asn) callback but it is giving me error

My code is as under

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var IPToASN =require('ip-to-asn');
var whois = new IPToASN();
var whoisQuery = Promise.promisify(whois.query);

var IPsArray;

Promise.then(function(){
   //set IPsArray e.g.
   IPsArray = ['180.90.90.90','8.8.8.8'];
}).whoisQuery(IPsArray).then(
   function(results){//callback
      //process the ip-to-asn query result
      console.log (results);
   }
).catch(
   function (err) {
     log.error(err);
   }
);
```

Note: this is just a part of the code where am getting into trouble

the Error I am getting is

```
 /home/ehsan/node/Tutorials/06/tracerouteToText/traceboxToJSON.js:53
    ).whoisQuery("130.83.10.15").then(
      ^

TypeError: cp.execAsync(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).whoisQuery is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ehsan/node/Tutorials/06/tracerouteToText/traceboxToJSON.js:53:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
```

My main purpose is to execute next promise (where i am going to process)  the query results after they arrive

Answer (score 1):

the issue is simple, you are chaining promises the wrong way, change promise code to:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var IPToASN =require('ip-to-asn');
var whois = new IPToASN();
var whoisQuery = Promise.promisify(whois.query);

var IPsArray = ['180.90.90.90','8.8.8.8'];

whoisQuery(IPsArray).then(function(results){//callback
      //process the ip-to-asn query result
      console.log (results);
}).catch(function (err) {
 log.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @mido . i tried this but i got following error

`{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1]
  cause: 
   { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1]
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1' },
  isOperational: true,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1' }`

I tried using ip-to-asn package without promisification and it works fine..